# Weird way servers are getting added in baseline topology

Tags: java, gridgain

I have two development machines, both running Ignite in server mode on same network. Actually I started the server in the first machine and then started another machine. When the other machine starts, it is getting automatically added to the first one's topology.

Note:

1. when starting I've removed the work folder in both machines.
2. In config, I never mentioned any Ips of other machines.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? My intention is each machine should've separate topology.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [discovery documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery#section-multicast-ip-finder), Apache Ignite will employ multicast to find all nodes in a local network, forming a cluster. This is default mode of operation.

Please note that we don't really recommend using this mode for either development or production deployment, use static discovery instead (see the same documentation).

Comment: Will check. Thank you.